# Notice: Undefined variable: link in a function

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I'm trying to display the number of rows in a SQL table with a condition.

The table ***viaturas*** has 4 records. I want to count how many rows in the column ***estado*** match **"Inoperacional"**, in this case, 3 records.

---

I've created a function ***ViaturasInop()*** in ***viaturas.php***:

```
<?php
    function ViaturasInop()
    {   
        require_once "config.php";

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `viaturas` WHERE `estado` LIKE 'Inoperacional'";

        if ($result=mysqli_query($link,$query))
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

        return $rowcount;

        mysqli_close($link);
    }

    echo ViaturasInop();
?>
```

If run ***viaturas.php*** it correctly returns **3**.

---

In the page I want the result to be shown ***index.php*** in the HTML body I have the following to call the function:

```
<div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800"><?php echo ViaturasInop(); ?></div>
```

However in return I get the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:[...]\php\viaturas.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:[...]\php\viaturas.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: rowcount in C:[...]\php\viaturas.php on line 11

---

I've tried other alternatives, however, I always get the same error.

Comment: when using the `LIKE` operator you would typically do `... LIKE '%Inoperacional%'` otherwise it is the same as `where estado='Inoperacional';`

Comment: What is in `config.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** use require_once to obtain a mysqli connection in a function.

First of all, it will work only once, as the name suggests.

Besides, even if you overcome this limitation, creating a new connection in every function call will **destroy your database server**.

Instead, you must call `require_once "config.php";` **once** at the top of your script, and then use the `$link` variable to obtain the mysqli connection. In order to have the connection in a function you must pass it as a function parameter:

```
<?php
function ViaturasInop($link)
{   
    $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM `viaturas` WHERE `estado` = 'Inoperacional'";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    return $row[0];
}
```

now, in your index file, somewhere at the top add

```
require_once "config.php";
```

and then put

```
echo ViaturasInop($link);
```

wherever you need the number

Comment: On a side note, you should never use mysqli_num_rows to count rows in the table. only SELECT count(*) query must be used for the purpose